# Como remover um caractere repetido em sequência?

Tags: php

Como faço para remover os caracteres repetidos em sequencia com PHP?

Entrada:

> Ellizabetth

Saída:

> Elizabeth

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pode usar o `preg_replace`, um exemplo:

```
$var = 'Elliiiiiiiiiiizabetth';
$pattern = '/(.)\1+/';
$replace = '$1';
$resultado = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $var);
echo $resultado;
```

Resultado:

```
Elizabeth
```

Outro exemplo, em uma única linha, com o mesmo resultado:

```
echo preg_replace('/(.)\1+/', '$1', 'Elliiiiiiiiiiizabetth');
```

Comment: Se está usando `'` ao invés de `"` não vejo motivo para usar `\\ `, pode usar `'/(.)\1+/'` ou `'/(.*)\1+/'`. Se estivesse usando `"` deveria usar `"/(.)\\1+/"`, com `\\ `. De qualquer forma, ambos funcionam normalmente.

Comment: Inkeliz... grato pelo comentário. Já ajustei na pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

Uma outra alternativa é:

```
function unique($palavra){
    $p = str_split($palavra);
    return implode(array_map(function ($c) use ($p) { 
                      return ($c > 0 && $p[$c] == $p[$c - 1] ? '': $p[$c]); 
    }, array_keys($p)));
}


echo unique("Banana") . "\n";        // Banana
echo unique("Arara") . "\n";         // Arara
echo unique("assassinos") . "\n";    // asasinos
echo unique("Marreco") . "\n";       // Mareco
echo unique("Elllizabettth") . "\n"; // Elizabeth
echo unique("FooBaaar") . "\n";      // FoBar
echo unique("Woow") . "\n";          // Wow
echo unique("baazz") . "\n";         // baz
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/E2mnJ4)

Uma segunda alternativa é percorrer a *string* num *loop* `for` e verificar se a letra atual é igual a letra anterior:

```
function unique2($palavra){
    $ret = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($palavra); $i++){
        if ($i == 0 || $palavra[$i] != $palavra[$i - 1]) $ret .= $palavra[$i];
    }
    return $ret;
}

echo unique2("Banana") . "\n";        // Banana
echo unique2("Arara") . "\n";         // Arara
echo unique2("assassinos") . "\n";    // asasinos
echo unique2("Marreco") . "\n";       // Mareco
echo unique2("Elllizabettth") . "\n"; // Elizabeth
echo unique2("FooBaaar") . "\n";      // FoBar
echo unique2("Woow") . "\n";          // Wow
echo unique2("baazz") . "\n";         // baz
```

[Ver `demonstração`](https://ideone.com/9GzQHe)

### **Nota**

Ambas as funções são *case-sensitive*, ou seja, difere letras maiúsculas e minusculas, para resolver isso use a [função `strtolower`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) em ambas as letras que serão comparadas, ou fazer a comparação usando a [função `strcasecmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php).